# Click event triggers twice

Tags: jquery

I append an image to use as button.

```
$('.vCSS_input_addtocart').after('<img id="custom_btn_addtocart" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/reverb/images/buttons/btn_addtocart.gif">');
```

On my image onClick event I'm triggering click event of another button but it seems like it is firing twice.

```
$('#custom_btn_addtocart').click(function(){
  $('.vCSS_input_addtocart').trigger('click');
});
```

I tried various approaches like checking `is_clicked=false` or `unbind("click").click()` and still no luck :(

Button tag I'm clicking is

```
<input class="vCSS_input_addtocart" type="image" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/reverb/images/buttons/btn_addtocart.gif" name="btnaddtocart" onclick="return addToCart(this.form, this);">
```

Here is addToCart function http://pastebin.com/Ysx1FSWS

Comment: Can you replicate this in a jsFiddle or some other live scenario?

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere, add more of the jquery you use.

Comment: @David unfortunately I can not replicate it in a jsFiddle

Comment: @Alin I pasted addToCart function here http://pastebin.com/Ysx1FSWS Let me know if it helps to make it more clear

Comment: @AZee: That suggests very strongly that the problem is in other code not shown here.

Comment: @David it looks like you are correct. Let me know what else I need to share to make it more clear? When I click `vCSS_input_addtocart` manually it works fine showing soft cart popup and not refreshing the page but when I click on my custom button it refreshes the page instead of display soft cart popup and increase product quantity to double from where I assume it triggers twice.

Comment: @PranavCBalan No, only one element.

Comment: @AZee: Don't assume anything.  If the page is being refreshed then the JavaScript is being entirely reset back to a new initial state.  It can't modify page state between page loads.  Perhaps this button is part of a form and that form is posting to the page?  Maybe this causes both server-side and client-side code to modify the value independently, causing the double update?  I'm mostly guessing at this point.

Comment: @David Yes man you get it 100% correct. I just tested unbinding onclick event of `vCSS_input_addtocart` and triggering the click event again which as a result submits the form. It redirects to shoppingcart.asp as defined in form action adding product to the cart. Now I am just trying to remove form action and triggering onClick if that makes sense or if I just change input type to button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this work by

```
$('.vCSS_input_addtocart').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
}).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem of event propagation in your case ,try using `return false`

```
$('#custom_btn_addtocart').click(function(){
  $('.vCSS_input_addtocart').trigger('click');
  return false;
});
```

and use `return false` in `.vCSS_input_addtocart` click event handler also.

Comment: @AZee..post your `.vCSS_input_addtocart` click event handler also

Comment: here is the addToCart function http://pastebin.com/Ysx1FSWS and I don't have direct access to it

Answer (score 0):

try preventDefault() and stopPropagation()

```
$('#custom_btn_addtocart').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $('.vCSS_input_addtocart').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: using `return false` and using both `e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();` is one and the same thing.

Comment: @Kartikeya you are right. Saw your answer only after i posted mine

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0oc4qy9/) :

```
$('#custom_btn_addtocart').click(function(){
   $('.vCSS_input_addtocart').trigger('click');
});

$('.vCSS_input_addtocart').click(function(){
    alert('test');
    $('.vCSS_input_addtocart').after('<img id="custom_btn_addtocart" src="/v/vspfiles/templates/reverb/images/buttons/btn_addtocart.gif">');
})
```